# Is a premium, softer mattress worth the extra money?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Innkeepers around Hyrule offer the option of a 'Soft Mattress' at double the price. When asked the difference though, they reveal themselves to be singularly untalented salespeople, rambling about the bed being stuffed with 'premium cucco feathers' that will leave Link 'more energized'.

Money is tight, so I haven't bothered to try it out. What good is a Soft Bed?

Comment: #WeirdShitGamersSay  out of context

Comment: It just gives you bonus hearts. You can get it cheaper for eating food.

Answer (score 12):

A soft bed grants you an extra heart temporarily.

The [IGN Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Highland_Stable) for the Highland Stable states:

> ...depending on your room choice (a soft bed gets you an extra temporary heart).

This [GameFAQs forum](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75069050) says the same, and also states that in Zora's domain, there is a water bed that grants 3 hearts, and a full extra stamina bar:

> And if you reach Zora's Domain, they have a water bed that gives you 3 extra hearts and a full extra stamina bar for 80 rupees a stay.

Comment: There's also the spa in Gerudo Town with an 80-rupee spa treatment that gives the 3 hearts/1 stamina bar boost, and I think I might have seen other 80-rupee bed options.

Comment: Goron City Inn has an 80 rupee "plus massage" option that adds a few extra hearts (I believe 3, but can;t remember for sure).

Comment: In fact, each one of the 4 Divine Beast cities has a "super premium" option that gives 3 extra hearts and 1 stamina wheel. Those are also flavoured to the respective tribe.